# Trying to compile OpenCV program, but getting LNK2038 error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I have followed [this](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.no/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html) tutorial for setting up OpenCV with Visual Studio 2012 and have changed all references to x86 to x64 like the tutorial suggested. But when running the example code given I get the following error message (in addition to 236 other):

`error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in Source.obj   c:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\NewProject\NewProject\opencv_core246d.lib(array.obj)    NewProject`

I'm not sure how to solve this and other suggested solutions given for the same error message has not worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is referring to your `RunTime Library`, you can edit this in your project properties:

- Right click on your project name in the solution explorer
- Click `C/C++`, then navigate to `Code Generation`.
- From here find the section named `Runtime Library`.

In the dropdown box you can the select a number of different settings.

Select the option which matches the runtime specified in your error and click apply.

You should probably clean and rebuild your project after making these changes